# Why do empty objects take more memory than non-empty ones?

Tags: node.js, optimization, memory, v8, jit

I found out V8 objects have quite of bit of memory overhead:  I had a array of mostly empty objects; it requires a whopping 64 bytes per element. (For comparison, Java requires 16 bytes.)

```
$ node --expose-gc  -e '
  gc();
  const start = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
  var a = Array(50 * 1000);
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = {};
  gc();
  console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - start)
'
3231304
```

Then I found I could reduce my memory usage 37% by adding a dummy property to my objects.

```
$ node --expose-gc  -e '
    gc();
    const start = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed;
    var a = Array(50 * 1000);
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) a[i] = {lifeTheUniverseAndEverything:42};
    gc(); 
    console.log(process.memoryUsage().heapUsed - start)
'
2028440
```

Why does adding a property to my objects reduce my memory usage?

```
$ node -v
v12.7.0

$ uname -a
Linux paul 4.15.0-70-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 10:36:11 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Verified on macOS 10.14 with node v8.12.0. Even more weirdness: if we do `{ var c = "xxxx" + i + "xxxx"; a[i] = {c:42}; }` in the loop, it takes 2271136 bytes - but if we do 
`{ var c = "xxxx" + i + "xxxx"; a[i] = {c:c}; }` suddenly it takes 5860328 bytes! I initially thought it might have something to do with V8's object shape optimization but those results make me question that...

Comment: @nneonneo the second result is unsurprising as you are storing a number of (different) ~15-character strings. 30 bytes extra for 100k elements...an extra 3MB.

Comment: It's funny though because the *keys* in both cases are large strings which should have to be stored - and yet they don't make a measurable impact on the size.

Comment: @nneonneo, I think you meant to write `{[c]:42}` for the first example, not `{c:42}`.

Comment: Oh ah, my bad. My JS is clearly rusty - yes, I wanted `[c]:42`. This makes the results much more in line with expectation, so now I am confident I have the right answer (below).

Answer (score 4):

Node (V8) makes the following assumption: if your object is empty `{}` then it will probably have properties added to it. Therefore, it allocates enough space for four properties in the object itself.

On the other hand, if the object literal has properties already then it will not allocate any extra space to save memory.

This is why you see empty objects as taking ~64 bytes.

Information partially cobbled together from reading V8 blog posts, as well as the very informative breakdown from Matt Zeunert: https://www.mattzeunert.com/2017/03/29/v8-object-size.html

Comment: V8 developer here. I can confirm this: empty objects created with `{}` pre-allocate some space for future properties. Modern JavaScript engines are optimized for performing well on real-world code, which often has a side effect of looking "weird" in reduced tests / microbenchmarks.

Comment: @jmrk, I will defend myself by saying this was real code that created usually-empty objects :) But yes I can see how that is probably usually the right thing to do.

Comment: Isn't this a problem for graph data structures?  Empty set is often used as Null Objects to avoid having to check for undefined on every access, and empty leaf nodes could easily represent half the object count in a tree.

Comment: A leaf node would usually have some data attached (e.g. node label), so the object wouldn't be empty. A non-existent leaf would usually be represented as a null in the parent.